# Remove middle of name in bash

Tags: bash, shell, rename, mv

I have 300+ files named:

```
T1_0000106_FS1_MAX_5743.nii.gz  T1_0000214_FS1_MAX_5475.nii.gz
T1_0000107_FS1_MAX_5477.nii.gz  T1_0000215_FS1_MAX_6162.nii.gz
```

I would like to remove everything between T1 and _5/6*.nii.gz so:

```
T1_5743.nii.gz  T1_5475.nii.gz
T1_5477.nii.gz  T1_6162.nii.gz
```

I can't figure out why it isn't working; I tried (from another post):

```
 for file in *.gz;
 do new_name=$(sed 's/_[^.]*_/_g' <<< "new_name");
 mv "$file" "$new_name"; done
```

and variations of rename/sed but nothing changes.

Comment: Surely you get error messages from both `sed` and `mv` when you run that script.  Consider paying attention to what they say.

Comment: I suggest to use Perl's standalone `rename` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with your script include, at least,

- `s/_[^.]*_/_g` is not a valid `sed` command.  You appear to want `s/_[^.]*_/_/g`, or in this case, `s/_[^.]*_/_/` would do fine as well.
- `<<< "new_name"` redirects the literal string `new_name` into `sed`.  Possibly you mean `<<< "$new_name"`

Personally, though, I would not bother with `sed` for this job, especially if you have a large number of files.  Bash is perfectly capable of doing fairly complex string manipulation itself, and your needs don't push it too hard.  Consider:

```
for f in *.gz; do
    # The value of $f with the longest trailing match to _* removed
    head=${f%%_*}

    # The value of $f with the longest leading match to *_ removed
    tail=${f##*_}

    new_name="${head}_${tail}"

    # Sanity check and avoid needless errors
    if [ "$f" != "$new_name" ]; then
        mv "$f" "$new_name"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
for i in *_5*.nii.gz *_6*.nii.gz;do a=${i%%_*};b=${i##*_};[[ $i != $a"_"$b ]] && mv $i $a"_"$b;done
```

Edited Following suggestion that the file could already be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Bash's built-in string substitution and its `extglob` option simplify the replacement of the middle part:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

for file in T1_*.nii.gz; do
  echo mv -- "$file" "${file/_+([^.])_/_}"
done
```

Remove the `echo`  or pipe the output to a shell, if it matches your expectations.

Here is the output of my own test:

```sh
mv -- T1_0000106_FS1_MAX_5743.nii.gz T1_5743.nii.gz
mv -- T1_0000107_FS1_MAX_5477.nii.gz T1_5477.nii.gz
mv -- T1_0000214_FS1_MAX_5475.nii.gz T1_5475.nii.gz
mv -- T1_0000215_FS1_MAX_6162.nii.gz T1_6162.nii.gz
```